# Perl substr based on bytes

Tags: perl, utf-8, amazon-simpledb

I'm using SimpleDB for my application. Everything goes well unless the limitation of one attribute is 1024 bytes. So for a long string I have to chop the string into chunks and save it.

My problem is that sometimes my string contains unicode character (chinese, japanese, greek) and the `substr()` function is based on character count not byte.

I tried to use `use bytes` for byte semantic or later 
`substr(encode_utf8($str), $start, $length)` but it does not help at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of perl you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTF-8 was engineered so that character boundaries are easy to detect. To split the string into chunks of valid UTF-8, you can simply use the following:

```
my $utf8 = encode_utf8($text);
my @utf8_chunks = $utf8 =~ /\G(.{1,1024})(?![\x80-\xBF])/sg;
```

Then either

```
# The saving code expects bytes.
store($_) for @utf8_chunks;
```

or

```
# The saving code expects decoded text.
store(decode_utf8($_)) for @utf8_chunks;
```

Demonstration:

```
$ perl -e'
    use Encode qw( encode_utf8 );

    # This character encodes to three bytes using UTF-8.
    my $text = "\N{U+2660}" x 342;

    my $utf8 = encode_utf8($text);
    my @utf8_chunks = $utf8 =~ /\G(.{1,1024})(?![\x80-\xBF])/sg;

    CORE::say(length($_)) for @utf8_chunks;
'
1023
3
```

Comment: @Borodin, Yes and no. It wouldn't make a difference to the regex engine, but it would make a difference to the reader. We want to match where the previous match left off, so let's not hide that.

Comment: @mob, Thanks, but it's UTF-8's designers that were clever. They specifically engineered UTF-8 so that character boundaries are easy to detect.

Answer (score 2):

`substr` operates on 1-byte characters unless the string has the UTF-8 flag on. So this will give you the first 1024 bytes of a decoded string:

`substr encode_utf8($str), 0, 1024;`

although, not necessarily splitting the string on *character boundaries*. To discard any split characters at the end, you can use:

```
$str = decode_utf8($str, Encode::FB_QUIET);
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily split the string on character boundaries, so the OP couldn't call `decode_utf8` on an individual chunk (which might be OK).

Comment: Incorrect; substr operates on characters (whatever their size in bytes may be), not bytes.

Comment: @mob: they could, passing  `Encode::FB_QUIET` as the second parameter.